# How to store off heap data on Apache Ignite 2.0

Tags: caching, ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

```
CacheConfiguration<String, JSONObject> conf = new CacheConfiguration<String, JSONObject>();
conf.setName("ABC");
conf.setWriteThrough(true);
conf.setReadThrough(true);
conf.setMemoryMode(CacheMemoryMode.OFFHEAP_TIERED);
conf.setOffHeapMaxMemory(0);
```

This is my cache configuration in ignite 1.9 but when I upgrade Apache Ignite from 1.9 to 2.0 I am getting error at last two line of configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since version 2.0 with default configuration Ignite stores entries in off-heap and there is no such method like setMemoryMode anymore.

You can read about new memory architecture and find new configuration parameters [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/page-memory).

Comment: but when I have checked on web Console it's showing all entries stored  on onHeap

Comment: try to check it by using cache.size(CachePeekMode.OFFHEAP)